# Creating a dynamic sized array of fixed sized int arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, fixed

For some reason this is giving me more trouble than i thought...

```
int *myArray[3];

myArray = new int[mySize];
```

does not work...

I've used a typedef before in a similar manner and it worked perfectly, but this time i dont want to create the typedef

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Do you mean `myArray[0]=new int[mySize];`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One might be tempted to do this:

```
::std::vector<int[3]> myArray;
```

Because `vector` is so nice for dynamically sized arrays. Unfortunately, while that declaration works, the resulting `vector` is unusable.

This will be just as efficient, if you have `::std::array` (a C++11 feature) and it will actually work:

```
::std::vector< ::std::array<int, 3> > myArray;
```

If you can do this, I would highly recommend it. `vector` is much nicer and safer to deal with than an array you have to allocate yourself with `new`.

Otherwise, try this:

```
typedef int inner_array_t[3];
inner_array_t *myArray = new inner_array_t[mySize];
```

And since you don't want to use a typedef for some odd reason, you can unwrap it like so:

```
int (*myArray)[3] = new int[mySize][3];
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that c++ vectors have little to no overhead on the top of an array (a small amount of memory overhead, I believe access times remain the same). Unless you are interfacing with C code or something else that requires arrays, it's almost always better to use STL vectors.

Comment: @ShaunBouckaert: Even if you are interfacing with C code, there are ways to get a pointer that can be passed to C code in a pinch. You just have to make sure the vector isn't modified while the C code is executing.

Comment: I don't think `std::vector<int[3]> myArray;` actually works, because C style arrays do not fulfill the requirements of a `vector`. What would you `push_back` into the vector? Something like `int a[3]; myArray.push_back(a);` doesn't work.

Comment: @Fred I am sure you are right, even though vector can re-allocate memory to expand to fit more arrays the size of the array is to hold is non deterministic. Though, could you not have a vector of pointers to arrays, the pointers would be a fixed size

Comment: @thecoshman: Or you could have a `std::vector<std::array<int, 3>>`.

Comment: @FredOverflow: The compiler accepts the declaration. But you are right. The resulting vector is unusable. And I thought I was being very clever. _sigh_ Oh, well.

Answer (score 6):

```
int (*myArray)[3] = new int[mySize][3];
```

?

Answer (score 3):

```
int *myArray[3];
```

This means "`myArray` shall be an array of three pointers-to-int".

You presumably wanted "`myArray` shall be a pointer-to-(array of three ints)". That is spelled `int (*myArray)[3]`.

This sort of thing is much easier with typedefs.

```
typedef int datum[3];
datum* myArray = new datum[mySize]; // no fuss, no muss.
```

But seriously, just use `std::vector`. And make an actual struct for your group-of-three-integers. Or, if it really should behave like an array, use `boost::array` so that you at least get the behaviour of a first-class type.